# AngularJS binding issues

Tags: angularjs

When I do the following in my code

```
<pre>{{uploader.queue.indexOf(item)|json}}</pre>
```

I get an index of the element that I am looking for but if I do something like this

> removeAllFiles(uploader.queue.indexOf(item))

The result is always

> -1

Comment: Are you sure `uploader.queue.indexOf(uploader.queue.indexOf(item))` is what you want to do? The inner function returns an index and you look for that index in the same array.

Comment: Good catch, just pasted it wrong sorry, always get confused by SO editor.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? If your `remove` call is in a controller you need to use `$scope.uploader`.

Comment: @eugenekgn Take a look at my answer......

Comment: @eugenekgn is that your requirement

Comment: Yes but for some reason item is undefined 0 to x index.

Comment: can you show me your code....so that i show you where it goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/15/)**

**html**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="main" ng-controller="Controller">
<div ng-repeat="uploader in uploaders">
      <button ng-click="removeAllFiles(uploader.queue.indexOf(item))">{{uploader.queue.indexOf(item)|json}}
      </button> 
</div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
angular.module('main', []);
// Main Controller
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.item = 'N'; 
    $scope.uploaders = [{
        clickable: true,
        id:1,
        queue: "ABC-Name"
    }, {
        clickable: false,
        id:2,
        queue: "XYZ-Name"
    }, {
        clickable: true,
        id:3,
        queue: "LMN-Name"
    }];

    $scope.removeAllFiles = function(item) {
     console.log(item);
    }
}
```